# Rhapsody java api - How to add an Object Model Diagram to a Class?

Tags: class, diagram, java, rhapsody

I am using the Rhapsody Java API to create some plugins in order to get automations features. I am trying to create an Object Model Diagram from a Class, but there is no functions in order to do it.

Basically I would like to do something like :

```
IRPClass cla = prj.addClass("Class");
IRPObjectModelDiagram omd = cla.addObjectModelDiagram("My OMD");
```

However, the addObjectModelDiagram() function is unavailable to a class.
I tryied to use ChangeTo() to the class to turn it into a Pkg then turn it back to a class without success, and to do the same with the OMD by creating an other type of diagram supported by IRPClass and then by turning it into an OMD. It didn't worked neither.

Does anyone have a solution in order to help me ?

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Thomas,

IRPModelElement has a generic "add" method called addNewAggr (see javadoc below).
In general, because of its open nature, I would only use this method in cases where you don't have a dedicated method. (Not every type of element can be added to every other type of element, so you have to be careful when using this. But in this case, you're talking about something that can be done in the UI - adding an OMD to a class, so there shouldn't be any problems.)

[javadoc for addNewAggr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpTnx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already created a class,
1. Determine IRPModelElements that you want to use in OMD. I.e classes, objects, link, associations, etc.
2. You can collect them using

```
implPackage.getNestedElementsByMetaClass("Class", 1); // 1 means one level, you can increase it if you have to go deeper nests.
IRPModelElement implClass = null;
for(int i = 1; i < numberOfClasses+1 ; i++) {
    elementInCollection = (IRPModelElement)classesOfImplPack.getItem(i);
    if( elementInCollection.getMetaClass().equals("Class") && elementInCollection.getDisplayName().equals(componentName+"_Class") )
    {
        implClass = elementInCollection;
        break;
    }
 }
```

2. Create a collection to collect them. (I just added a class as an example.)

   IRPCollection packages = app.createNewCollection();
   packages.setSize(3);
   packages.setModelElement(1, implObject);
   packages.setModelElement(2, association);
   packages.setModelElement(3, link);
   //Assuming that you have collected them before.
3. Determine what to be drawn in OMD:

   IRPCollection relTypes = app.createNewCollection();
   relTypes.setSize(2);
   relTypes.setString(1, "Link");
   relTypes.setString(2, "Association");
4. Create OMD

   IRPObjectModelDiagram testerOMD = testerPackage.addObjectModelDiagram(componentName+"_Tester_OMD");
5. Populate Diagram

   testerOMD.populateDiagram(packages, relTypes, "fromto");